# bootstrap override only 1 nav color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i would like to ask You how to change the color of only one nav 'button' in bootstrap 3, for instance, i want to format only the news section ( to male it different) how to do it to change the bg color , hover etc of only this button ( tab element) the other will contintue to use the main style ?

```
 <nav>
    <ul class="nav nav-justified">
      <li><a href="/news">news</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://shop.1.com/">shop</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a class to the particular `<li>` element (let's name the class `"li-news-item"`) holding the "news" link:

```
<li class="li-news-item"><a href="/news">news</a></li>
```

...and use that as a selector to style the contained `a`:

```
nav ul li.li-news-item a {
    color: purple;
    background-color: white;
}

nav ul li.li-news-item a:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: purple;
}
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epJEeQ)

P.S.: Since your question is explicitly asking how to change a particular `nav` item color, I've made the CSS rule [*specific enough*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to only apply on the `a` contained in the list item with class `"li-news-item"` of your `nav`.

Comment: I believe the question was how to style the anchor using only CSS, without touching the html (which is probably rendered by some framework). But I might be wrong.

Comment: If so it should be explicitly specified in the question (which it's not).

Comment: I guess you're right. But I'm also guessing, from how the question is formulated, that specificity is not the strongest point of this question's author.

Comment: IMHO, receiving an answer which might also contribute towards extending the knowledge of the OP by introducing him to concepts he might not be familiar with (CSS specificity is not trivial knowledge) is never a bad thing.

Comment: Do you actually believe the OP had an epiphany when you suggested he/she can add a unique class name to the element? Besides, if the current `background-color` comes from a, let's say: `#navbar nav ul.nav li a`  selector, **your code does not work**, so you're creating even more confusion around a concept that is currently vague. What he/she needs to learn is how to inspect/debug and build stronger selectors than the ones that **currently apply**. That would *really* be a step forward. IMHO.

Comment: What you're doing at the moment is pure speculation. Do you see `nav` wrapped in `#navbar` in the code? No. Does this solution qualify as a potential solution for the OP based on the formulation of his question? Yes. I could make the same argument about your answer: what if the `href` changes from `/news` to something else? Your solution won't work as well—but hey, I'm speculating.. Bottom line: you're entitled to your own opinion, hence why you have provided an answer of your own, so I think this conversation is becoming moot.

Comment: thanks for reply, but still not working, i see only white link in a state ( not hover !! ) the main CSS remains right ?

Comment: Hey, as Andrei told you in the comments of his answer, you can edit your answer (or provide a Codepen or JSFiddle) to show us how the structure of your menu looks like. That way you can get a more accurate answer. And yes the main CSS remains, just append the new CSS in your stylesheet.